# Connect to MySQL over SSH with agent using MySQL Workbench (or other)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ssh, mysql-workbench

I use for connecting any SSH Session the Plugin keeagent in my Keepass (it works like pageant). So I haven never enter my Password an by private Key is stored in my keepass file. It exists several tools, that works fine with using a SSH agent. But I don't find a way to use a SSH Tunnel using an agent in MySQL Workbench.

Is it possible to connect with MySQL Workbench over SSH Tunnel using an agent?

If not, does anyone knows, which tool supports this feature?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL Workbench does not support using an SSH agent when SSH tunnelling, only password and passphrase-less key. On the latter: it supports SSH keys only when they do not have a passphrase. This is as of MySQL Workbench 8.0.19.

The TablePlus client does support using an agent; more specifically it uses the standard `ssh_config` to extract the various options to use when connecting via an SSH host.

Answer (score 0):

First, MySQL Workbench itself can create an SSH tunnel. You can determine all the details when you choose a connection to be TCP/IP over SSH.

And MySQL Workbench can also use any existing tunnel in the system (be it from keeagent or putty). You just have to know the used local port for the tunnel and use that for the connection in MySQL Workbench. It appears in WB as if you have a local connection then.

Comment: Hi, thans for reply, but I try to connect to database using the function: TCP/IP over SSH in MySQL workbench. This feature needs a directory path to the key file an I cannot configure for using an existant agent (like pageant oder keeagent) for establishing the ssh connection.

Comment: Those key agents manage the key files for you, which is convenient. MySQL Workbench's SSH implementation (currently the paramiko library) however wants direct access to a keyfile, but only if you are using key based authentication. Try to locate the keyfiles your key agent manages, e.g. in your user directory, subfolder `.ssh`. This folder is such a standard that many implementations automatically use the keyfile `id_rsa` if it exists there.

Comment: Okay thanks, just to clarify, it is not possible to use in this case the agent, because MySQL Workbench needs the direct access to the file?

Comment: Well, what I meant to say was that **if** WB is used for SSH access it needs direct access to the key file. However, it's easy for WB to use an existing tunnel, created by another application (as mentioned in my answer). In this case the other app is managing the key file.